# When would bias regularisation and activation regularisation be necessary?

Tags: neural-networks, keras, regularization, weights

For Keras on TensorFlow, a layer class constructor comes with these:

- `kernel_regularizer`=...
- `bias_regularizer`=...
- `activity_regularizer`=...

For example, Dense layer:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense#arguments_1

The first one, `kernel_regularizer` is easy to understand, it regularises weights, makes weights smaller to avoid overfitting on training data only.

Is `kernel_regularizer` enough? When should I use `bias_regularizer` and `activity_regularizer` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regularizer's are used as a means to combat over fitting.They essentially create a cost function penalty which tries to prevent quantities from becoming to large.  I have primarily used kernel regularizers. First I try to control over fitting using dropout layers. If that does not do the job or leads to poor training accuracy I try the Kernel regularizer. I usually stop at that point. I think activity regularization would be my next option to prevent outputs from becoming to large. I suspect weight regularization effectively can pretty much achieve the same result.